# How do I determine which javascript is modifying the DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, malware

I'm dealing with a hacked Joomla site where the attacker cleverly buried his code somewhere in the included javascript files. The site loads dozens of these files from all over the place, and the vast majority of the scripts are packed and obfuscated already, making step-through debugging very nearly impossible. Furthermore, I know from the samples I've found already that the attacker's javascript code is *also* packed using the same system and is visually indistinguishable from the "legitimate" code.

I know that somewhere in the code that executes browser side that an iframe is created and attached to the DOM to pull in the more serious exploit code. But I don't know which code in which file is causing this to happen.

Is there a way to trap this event in the browser and see where the code being executed was loaded from?

Presumably this would be in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Best place to start would be inspecting from where the scripts are getting downloaded...

Comment: Also you can download the original and check it against diff tool

Comment: @deostroll everything downloads from site-local. But one of the local scripts is corrupted and I can't tell which one.

Comment: @quarry if I could download the originals then I wouldn't even bother with trying to figure out which one was different.

Comment: If on Windows, you can install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) + [JavaScript Formatter](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/extensions.asp) and then inside Fiddler `Rules` menu option, enable `Make JavaScript pretty`. This will on-the-fly unminify files before loading, so you can inspect it in Firebug and Chrome. In Chrome, you can already do it with built-in JS prettifier. In Firebug you can also use [JS deminifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/)

Comment: To look for iframe addition, you may try to go to `Script` or `Net` tab of Firebug and search for `iframe` text (with the options of respectively, `Multiple files` / `Response bodies` on the right-click on the search field).

Comment: @jakub.g [this site](http://jsbeautifier.org/) will also unpack javascript, as I think firebug will also do on its own, but unfortunately that's not enough. I eventually solved this by brute-force, but I think the question itself is still useful if there is indeed an answer.